# set value of listItem in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem

```
 if (currentMap.EditMap != null)
 {
ddlEditMapGroupName.SelectedIndex = ddlEditMapGroupName.Items.IndexOf(ddlEditMapGroupName.Items.FindByText(currentMap.EditMap));
}
```

sets the value of the drop down box to the stored value...but if currentMap.Edit map is null how can I set the value to the text of the listItem?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditMapGroupName" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select Group" Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question...

It sounds like you've got a dropdown list that already has a bunch of listitems in it (?).

And you're trying to set the selected item to match another control on the page.

One strategy I use (for certain cases) is to put a record into whichever table you're pulling your dropdownlist data from that says, simply 'Not Selected'.  Then, make sure that whatever you're using to query data for your dropdownlist pulls that 'Not Selected' record into the list.

With that, you can simply add an 'else' clause to your control statement there to set the selected value to 'Not Selected' when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (currentMap.EditMap != null)
     {
    ddlEditMapGroupName.SelectedIndex = ddlEditMapGroupName.Items.IndexOf(ddlEditMapGroupName.Items.FindByText(currentMap.EditMap));
    }
    else
    {
       ddlEditMapGroupName.SelectedValue = "0";
    }

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditMapGroupName" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select Group" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You could simply set the `SelectedValue` property to the default value which in your case is `Select Group` and its `value` is `0`...

This *should* be done once your `DropDownList` is already bind to a data source.